# Getting the root of a project in vercel during an api request

Tags: next.js, vercel

Locally I was using `process.cwd()` to get the root directory of a project. That works fine until I try it on vercel, where that doesn't work, due to the way api requests are handled by vercel. How can I get the project-source in vercel?

This is (presumably) the directory it takes on `process.cwd()`:

```
baseDir: '/var/task/guestbook'
```